# Returning by reference not supported

Tags: php, doctrine, phpunit

in my current project i use doctrine and a listener, checking for certain changes to trigger cache-invalidation.

In my test, due to the use of `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity)` i get the following error:

```
Returning by reference not supported
```

The underlying code for this is inside the Doctrine class [UnitOfWork](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L517):

```
public function & getEntityChangeSet($entity)
{
```

which i obviously won't/can't change.
The code that calls it already worked in production:

```
$args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity)
```

I updated to the latest stable PHPUnit version that we support (4.8) and can't go higher since then i'd had to rewrite all tests (*due to serveral methods that became deprecated*).

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may use `doctrine/orm` of version 2.5.
It has not this passing by reference, only `master` holds it

Comment: Sorry, do you say i should use 2.5 (which i am) or i should use master?

Comment: In 2.5 there is no this reference call (as far as I see) https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L526

Comment: I am using master 2.5
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L517

Comment: But how do you have your dependency in composer.json? I've just checked it out with         "doctrine/orm": "^2.5" - it imports version without &amp;

Comment: i have tried "2.5" and "^2.5" and even "2.5.4" with each giving me the & in the code.